# I can't detect programmatically value change in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm very new at angularjs and I'm in trouble,
I have **html** like this:

```
<section class="content" ng-app="offer">
    <div ng-controller="OfferController">
    ...
    <input name="Attachment" type="file" class="file_up" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().change(this)" ng-model="Attachment" />
    <span>{{Attachment}}</span> //i can't get it
    ...
    </div>
</section>
```

and **script:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('offer', []);

myApp.controller('OfferController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.change = function (element) {
        if (element.files.length > 0) {
            $scope.Attachment = element.files[0].name;
        }
        else {
            $scope.Attachment = "";
        }
        console.log($scope.Attachment); // I can get changed value in console
    }
}]);
```

**image:**
[image: i can not get span with value]

I **can** get changed value in console but I **can't** get in html side when input's value change. Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you change model from outside Angular's digest cycle, you have to inform framework manually that it must run watchers again. You can use `$scope.$apply()` for this:

```
$scope.change = function (element) {
    if (element.files.length > 0) {
        $scope.Attachment = element.files[0].name;
    }
    else {
        $scope.Attachment = "";
    }
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Or more concise:

```
$scope.change = function(element) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.Attachment = element.files.length ? element.files[0].name : '';
    });
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6quQlHJIvdD3QwtOhHrB?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As @dfsq pointed out in a comment, `ng-change` doesn't work out of the box for a file input, so I edited to include an alternative solution instead.

You could write a custom directive to handle a file input yourself, and make it update the property binding in `ng-model` (only one-way though).

```
.directive('input', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      if (!ctrl || attr.type !== 'file') {
        return;
      }

      var listener = function() {
        var file = element[0].files[0];
        var value = file && file.name;

        if (ctrl.$viewValue !== value) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(value); // update ng-model
          });
        }
      };

      element.on('change', listener);
    }
  }
})
```

This way, the `onchange` or `ng-change` is not needed, when user choose a file, the file name should be set to the property in `ng-model` right away.

```
<input type="file" name="Attachment" ng-model="Attachment" ng-change="change()" />
<span>{{ Attachment }}</span>
```

Example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/K3ZLoqNUPbo991b9ooq3?p=preview

**Original answer:** (this doesn't work for input type="file")

Instead of `onchange`, you should use `ng-change` instead.

Try changing this:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().change(this)"
```

To this:

```
ng-change="change($event.target)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it would be correct approach. Unfortunately `ngChange` does not support input type file. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/48b34ddb79d8e65cbdd0aa0ef15189a904887220/src/ng/directive/input.js#L866).

Comment: thanks, It did not help my question but gave up the idea for something else. upvoted:)

Comment: @dfsq Oh, thanks for letting me know. I will edit my answer to include alternative working solution.