# Programmatically changed value not detected by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is only my 2nd AngularJS project. I'm trying to add new functionality to an existing jQuery app rather than starting over.

The jQuery portion populates a div with several image thumbnails. The purpose of the new AngularJS features is to allow the user to edit the information for the photos - caption, photographer credit, and such. Clicking a thumbnail should trigger the Angular app to retrieve its info from the database for edit. My problem is, the image URL is never picked up by Angular.

The ng-app tag is placed on the page's body element, so everything should be visible to Angular. I have tried $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply with no success.  The URL of the clicked image does appear in expected locations, but the Angular model element "imgurl" never seems to get updated despite using ng-model="imgurl" on the text input field.

I have looked at similar questions such as these:

- [I can't detect programmatically value change in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409734/i-cant-detect-programmatically-value-change-in-angularjs)
- [AngularJS : ng-model binding not updating when changed with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873627/angularjs-ng-model-binding-not-updating-when-changed-with-jquery)

My existing jQuery, trying to push data into Angular

```
function populateImageForm(imageURL) {
    jQuery("#imageurltest").html("clicked image is " + imageURL); //show the URL of the clicked image
    //updates the image, but Angular doesn't see change: jQuery("#working-image").attr("src", imageURL);
    jQuery("#working-image").attr("ng-src", imageURL);
    jQuery("#wiurl").val(imageURL);
    }
```

HTML elements using Angular:

```
<img id="working-image" class="center-block img-responsive" ng-src={{imgurl}} imageonload />
<input id="wiurl" type="text" size="65" ng-model="imgurl"  />
```

Angular controller code:

```
app.controller("imageInfoControl", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.imgurl = "http://example.org/placeholder.jpg";

    $http.get("ng-get-image.php", {params:{"url": $scope.imgurl}} ).success(function(response){
        console.log (response);
        $scope.message = response.title;
        });

    $scope.$watch('imgurl', 
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('imgurl programmatically changed');
    });

$scope.$watch(function() {
      return $scope.message
    }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
      if(newVal !== null) {
        console.log('message programmatically changed to ' + $scope.message);
      }
    });

    }); 


app.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
                console.log (element);
                console.log (attrs);
                //doesn't seem to do anything: scope.$apply(attrs.imageonload); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884399/image-loaded-event-in-for-ng-src-in-angularjs
                scope.$digest;
                scope.message = attrs.src;
                console.log(scope.message);
                //alert('image is loaded');
            });
            element.bind('error', function(){
                alert('image could not be loaded');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Sample Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKCqFy3VX7Oa3s9s8HtV?p=preview)**

Make it as separate js file and call it in index under angular and jquery script

```
(function($, ng) {
    var $val = $.fn.val; // save original jQuery function
   // override jQuery function
  $.fn.val = function (value) {
    // if getter, just return original
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return $val.call(this);
    }
     // get result of original function
    var result = $val.call(this, value);
     // trigger angular input (this[0] is the DOM object)
    ng.element(this[0]).triggerHandler('input');
     // return the original result
    return result; 
  }
})(window.jQuery, window.angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use model as a property of an object.
Please try ng-model="data.imgurl".
Of course, you need to declare data object in the scope.

$scope.data = {}:
$scope.data.imgurl = "something.jpg";
Like this

Thank you